# git clone warning: failed to restrict file handles

Tags: git, github, git-for-windows

From the windows CLI, i run

```
git clone https://github.com/jef ...
```

It seems to clone the repository, but not without warnings, and I'm not sure if I should be concerned. This is a second development machine. The original was pushed from another.

This is the output:

```
C:\python-projects>git clone https://github.com/jeffplata/by-examp...

Cloning into 'by-example-account'...
warning: failed to restrict file handles (1450)

warning: failed to restrict file handles (1450)

warning: failed to restrict file handles (1450)

remote: Counting objects: 52, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
warning: failed to restrict file handles (1450)

remote: Total 52 (delta 11), reused 50 (delta 9), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (52/52), done.
```

I'm using Windows 7, git version 2.16.3.windows.1

(this is a django project repo)

What is causing this behavior? Is something broken from the repository source or clone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this bountysource](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/56384210-v2-16-3-git-5d726e0-x64-warning-failed-to-restrict-file-handles-1450) (and [PR 1595](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1595#issuecomment-378580728)), this might have been fixed in 2.17.

So first, make sure to upgrade to the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) to see if the issue persists.

The [OP JeffP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3312274/jeffp) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093771/git-clone-warning-failed-to-restrict-file-handles/50093986#comment87204459_50093986):

> Works:
>
> ```
> C:\python-projects>git clone github.com/jeffplata/by-ex
>    Cloning into 'by-example-account'... 
>    remote: Counting objects: 52, done. 
>    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done. 
>    remote: Total 52 (delta 11), reused 50 (delta 9), pack-reused 0 
>            Unpacking objects: 100% (52/52), done. 
>
> C:\python-projects>git version git version 2.17.0.windows.1
> ```

Comment: Works.      <code>C:\python-projects>git clone https://github.com/jeffplata/by-ex

    Cloning into 'by-example-account'...
    remote: Counting objects: 52, done.
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
    remote: Total 52 (delta 11), reused 50 (delta 9), pack-reused 0
    Unpacking objects: 100% (52/52), done.

    C:\python-projects>git version
    git version 2.17.0.windows.1</code> Sorry, got to lean how to use markdown

Comment: @JeffP Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.